# how wifi web authentication works?

Tags: authentication, wifi, web-authentication

Some wifi are open networks, but when we connect, it redirects to a web page for authentication. How does this work? how the future packets will be authenticated? Does it bind IP and MAC address (which can be easily spoofed)?

Comment: Consider the answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/306498/449361) in another SE community, and the term [Captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) in particular.

Comment: As a side note, the fact that the network is open means that there is **no encryption** on the network level of your packets. Anything you browse is available for anyone to see (and possibly tamper with).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works by remembering your MAC address. When you connect to a router – a firewall redirects you to a web page for authentication. If you pass authentication step then your MAC address is added to the whitelist.

It doesn't necessary map your MAC address to a specific IP. It just redirects all http(s) traffic to the authentication page if the MAC address is not in the whitelist.

Yes, MAC address can be spoofed easily. Using aircrack-ng toolkit you can monitor nearby clients connected to the WiFi and use their MAC address to skip the authentication.